# Why right side div is not side by side with the left side div?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a page on which I have a lot of divs and something I did (can't figure out what it is) is making the right side div appear below the right side div.

Here is an example page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=223

I am staring at this thing with firebug, but can't figure out why this is happening.  I even made the width of the left div much narrower, but still the right side div is not lining up next to the left side div.

Any idea what the problem is?

Thanks!!

Comment: You mean right side div appear below *left* side div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        ....  
        ....
        </div> <!-- Closes tabs div -->
        </div> <!-- Closes left div -->
         </div>      < ----  Here you need a closing div tag and the right menu goes up.

<div style="float: right; width: 225px;">
....  
........  
 ....
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<div>` with the `float:right` style is currently inside the `<div>` with with the `float:left` style (that may be the change you made). Just move the `<div>` you want to float right out of there and make it the immediate sibling of the left floated `<div>`

Comment: I keep trying to figure out where to place the extra </div> so that the right div is not in the left div, but I can't seem to get it right.  Where would you place the extra </div> so it would get aligned right?  Thanks!!

Comment: Probably immediately before the start of the right div, but check that you don't have any extra closing div tags further on in your code

Answer (score 1):

You HTML is incorrect. The right div is inside the left div. Check your markup.

Answer (score 1):

`.half_text` is 650px, the first `div` is 120px while the second `div` is 575px. Try setting the second's width to 530px. In `#suggestions` it looks like the right side shouldn't be more than 450px.

Hope this helps.